# Use day of the week to populate SharePoint Calendar

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-calendar

I have an `InfoPath` booking form that is going to be used to book swimming lessons. The twist is that the requirement requires the user to choose a day of the week for example Monday and it then needs to populate the calendar for 4 consecutive Mondays. My problem is how do I populate the calendar using the day of the week as the calendar uses Date data type to populate the calendar and on my form I can't use a date-picker as it has to be a drop down list with the values being the days of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around. You have to use a date piker and just add three hidden fields(week 2, week 3, week 4) and add a rule that uses add days and the day the user picks on the date picker will be the day one and for week 2 set rule to a rule and add 7 days to date picked for week 3 add 14 days to date picked and for week 4 add 21 days you will now be able to populate the calendar.